# What is the best way to identify places on gps?

Tags: android, gps

i'm trying to develop application with a gps that can know if i arrive at or leave a specific place.
I.E if i am at home so, the application know that and if i leaving my home the application know that too. or if i want to set the radius of my home. but i think the problem is that when i trying to running the appliction and search places every x time it could kill my battery.

**what is the best solution for that action? should i using services too?**
here is the class i made to get the place and the coordinates:

```
public class LocationMap extends Service implements LocationListener {
    public static final String LOG = "locationLogger";

    Context context;
    LocationManager manager;
    Location location;
    public static final int REFRESH = 1000*1;
    public static final int DISTANCE = 1*1;
    double lat,lng;
    boolean isGps,isWiFi;



    public LocationMap(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        getLocation();

    }

    private Location getLocation(){
        try {

            manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,REFRESH,DISTANCE,this);

            //Check who is on WiFi or GPS
            isWiFi = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);Log.d(LOG, "Wifi?="+isWiFi);
            isGps = manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);Log.d(LOG, "Gps?="+isGps);

            Log.d(LOG, "manager is not null?="+manager);
            if (manager != null) {
                if(isGps){
                    Log.d(LOG, "get last location from Gps");
                    location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                }else
                if(isWiFi){
                    Log.d(LOG, "get last location from WiFi");
                    location = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                }

                if (location != null) { 

                    lat = location.getLatitude();
                    lng = location.getLongitude();
                    Log.d(LOG, "lat="+lat +" lng="+lng);
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return location;
    }


    public String getPlace(){
        String placeName = "No place found, check your gps setting";
        try {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context);
            List<Address> address =geocoder.getFromLocation(getLat(), getLng(), 1);
                String country = address.get(0).getCountryName();
                String city = address.get(0).getLocality();
                String street = address.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                placeName = country+", "+city+", "+street;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return placeName;   
    }

    public double getLng(){
        return lng;
    }


    public double getLat() {
        return lat;
    }





    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }


}
```

sorry about my english. hope you understand me :)

Comment: The searchable keyword is "geofence".

Comment: where i can find the best tutorial i search about it and it's looks exactly what i need! thank you

Comment: Which tutorial is best is highly subjective.  Only you can decide which one speaks to you.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on your accuracy needed.
If the desired range is about 1 - 3km then there is a battery saving solution, I will not further explain here. (Using the devices Network locationg procider) 
For accuracy much better there is no way around using GPS always on,
which at my iphone 4 lasts about 8 hours.

Detection if arrival is simply done via entering inside a circle, defined by lat,lon, radius.

Inside circle is calculated by:

```
boolean isInside = currentLocation.distanceTo(circleCenterLongitude, circleCenterLatitude) < radiusMeters.
```